# How to check a checkbox based on value of its value attribute?

Tags: javascript

I have a table with id checkbox and the table is created dynamically as follows where one column is checkbox input. I want to get the value of value attribute so that i can check that checkbox depending on value of value attribute.

```
str +="<td><input type='checkbox' value='" + data['data'][i]['present_absent_flag '] + "'     
class='mycheckbox' id='id_" + data['data'][i]['attendance_id'] + "'></td>";    

$('#example').find('input:checkbox').each(function() {
                        var check_val=$('this').val();
                        console.log(check_val);
                        if(check_val==1){
                            $('this').attr('checked', true);
                        }

});
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [ternary operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/be21c7hw%28v=vs.94%29.aspx):

```
str +="<td><input type='checkbox' checked='" + (data['data'][i]['present_absent_flag '] ==1 ? "checked" : "") + "'     
class='mycheckbox' id='id_" + data['data'][i]['attendance_id'] + "'></td>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use:

```
$(this).prop('checked', true);
```

Instead of

```
$('this').attr('checked', true');
```

More info here: http://api.jquery.com/prop/

Comment: I am not able to get check_val value.

Comment: Oh yeah... remove the quotes around `this`: `var check_val=$(this).val();`